# Single alert dialog for entire application

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I have to display many error messages and alert dialogues in my application.
I do not want to use Toast, I prefer to use `AlertDialog`.

Instead of creating a new alert dialog in every activity, how do I create and maintain one alert dialog and just change the error message string in it?

Whatever activity I am in, I must be able to access the `AlertDialog` instance to show and dismiss it.

How can I achieve this? Kindly give me some lead on this.

Comment: create the dialog as a method with a parameter (like message) in a class and make it as static and call it where ever u need

Comment: http://androiddevblog.wordpress.com/2011/02/09/sharing-complex-dialog-interactions-across-multiple-activities/

Comment: follow as @G_S and also pass the context to that method,you can have that method in a new class.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

make one class and paste this function...(may be Utils.java)

```
public static void alertDialogShow(Context context, String message)
        {
            final AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context).create();
            alertDialog.setMessage(message);
            alertDialog.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
            {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                {
                    alertDialog.dismiss();
              } 
            }); 
            alertDialog.show();
        }
```

and call this by writing..

```
Utils.alertDialogShow(YourActivity.this,"Your Error Message")
```

Comment: Please don't name a utility class `Utils`... make it specific, organized. For example, this might go in a `AlertUtils` class instead, or `DialogUtils`. Think about who might be maintaining your code later, unless it's your own personal project (in which case, name it whatever you want as long as you remember what's in there).

Comment: @ChrisCirefice Thanks for your suggestion. I will keep in mind for next time answer in stackoverflow as well as in my current coding. Thanks again.!!

Answer (score 4):

You could always write a base class of Activity with your alertdialog call as a method and then for any of your activity classes instead of using extends Activity, use extends MyBaseActivity and then call the method whenever you need it by passing the string you want output.

Comment: This is a bad practice. Use a util class instead. Use composition over inheritance as showing a dialog can be needed by other class types in your app.

Answer (score 0):

I do something like this in a helper class

```
 public static void AlertBox(final Activity activity, final String title, final String message)
 {
     AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
     alertbox.setTitle(title);
     alertbox.setCancelable(false);
     alertbox.setMessage(message);
     alertbox.setNeutralButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
         activity.finish();
         }
 });

     alertbox.show();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/**
 * Class for showing validation message
 */

package com.prj.utility;

import com.prj.R;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.prj.utility.System;

public class ValidationPopup {

    Context mContext = null;

    public ValidationPopup(Context mContext) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.mContext = mContext;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param strTitle - title of dialog
     * @param strMessage - message to be shown in dialog
     * @param value - edit text object
     */
    public void showValidationDialog(String strTitle, String strMessage,
            final EditText value) {
        final AlertDialog dlgValidationPopUp = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext)
                .create();

        final LayoutInflater lyInflaterForDlgTitle = (LayoutInflater) mContext
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        LinearLayout lLayoutCustTitle = (LinearLayout) lyInflaterForDlgTitle
                .inflate(R.layout.custom_title, null);

        TextView tvTitle = (TextView) lLayoutCustTitle
                .findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        tvTitle.setText(strTitle);
        dlgValidationPopUp.setCustomTitle(lLayoutCustTitle);
        if (strMessage == null || strMessage.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("")) {

            //If there isn't any message in database for validation of the field, then DEFAULT_MESSAGE will be used
            strMessage = Config.DEFAULT_MESSAGE;
        }

        dlgValidationPopUp.setMessage(strMessage);
        dlgValidationPopUp.setCancelable(true);
        dlgValidationPopUp.setButton("OK",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        dlgValidationPopUp.dismiss();

                        //Edittext will be given focus if the field is edit text and it is not null
                        if (value != null)
                            value.requestFocus();
                    }
                });
        dlgValidationPopUp.show();

    }

}
```

You can make this class's object anywhere in your application as,

```
ValidationPopup vPopup = new ValidationPopup(mContext);
```

And call method `showValidationDialog` according to your need

```
vPopup.showValidationDialog("Alert Msg","This is message content", objectOfEditText);//You can pass null as third arg if its not for edittext.
```