# How to display same dialog in multiple activitiy?

Tags: android, dialog, android-asynctask

I have created a dialog in an activity. Using async task i will display that dialog periodically. Is it possible to display the dialog when i move to another activity also?

Comment: check my answer here....

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13561915/single-alert-dialog-for-entire-application/13561965#13561965

Answer (score 1):

I did it in 2 different ways in the past.

1) Creating a layout used as a dialog (imported in each activity-layout and hidden) that i showed when needed (you could also create an 'empty' activity that only popups that dialog and if you want the message.

2) Creating a CustomDialog class and using it (i used it to deal with customized font, but I will only put once in this code).

```
//main Activity:
     DialegError da = new DialegError(this);
     da.crearDialeg("APP ERROR", "this is an error");
```

---

```
//Error class
public class DialegError {
    private Activity a = null;

    public DialegError(Activity activity){
            a=activity;
    }

    /**
     * Default NO-MESSAGE errorDialog
     */
    public void crearDialeg(String titol){
        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(a)
            .setTitle( titol )
//          .setIcon(R.drawable.)
            .setPositiveButton( a.getString(R.string.button_aceptar), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    return;
                }
            })
            .show();
    }

    /**
     * Default errorDialog
     */
    public void crearDialeg(String titol, String cos){
        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(a)
            .setTitle( titol )
            .setMessage( cos )
//          .setIcon(R.drawable.)
            .setPositiveButton( a.getString(R.string.button_aceptar), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    return;
                }
            })
            .show();

     //Personalized font. No way to deal with the title text.
     Typeface font=Typeface.createFromAsset(a.getAssets(),"fonts/font_name.ttf");
     TextView textView = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
     textView.setTypeface(font);
     textView =  (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.button1);
     textView.setTypeface(font);
    }

    /**
     * Error Dialog that closes the invoker activity.
     */
    public void crearDialegError(String titol, String cos, int err){
        final Activity activitat = a;
        final int error = err;
        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activitat)
            .setTitle( titol )
            .setMessage( cos )
//          .setIcon(R.drawable.)
            .setPositiveButton( activitat.getString(R.string.button_aceptar), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    activitat.setResult(error, new Intent());
                    activitat.finish();
                }
            })
            .show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can make a button for showing dialog, in event onclick any code for showing dialog, and you set button click periodic.

```
public void getRunningClick(){
     new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                  //your code showing dialog
            }
        },(2*1000));
}
```

hope is help to you

Comment: Suppose the code is in Avtivity A, when i moves to Acitivity B, will the dialog gets open?

Comment: you create this method in class independent, and each class,ex class A and class B call this method.

Comment: No, i dont know in which activity user is, i need to find the active class and need to display it.