# Using Single AlertBox Method For The Entire Application In Android

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm getting the following error while declaring `AlertBox` method in common class and using it from other classes:

> "android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window
>   -- token null is not for an application"

```
private void AlertBox(String s, final String err, final Context con){ 
    AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(con).create(); 
    builder1.setMessage(s); builder1.setCancelable(true); 
    builder1.setPositiveButton( "Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() { 
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    }); builder1.show(); }
```

I have checked the post:

"[Single alert dialog for entire application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13561915/single-alert-dialog-for-entire-application/37475388#37475388)"
but none of the solutions is working for me.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: private void AlertBox(String s, final String err, final Context con){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(con).create();
        builder1.setMessage(s);
        builder1.setCancelable(true);

        builder1.setPositiveButton(
                "Ok",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        builder1.show();
    }

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
private void AlertBox(String title, final String err, final Context con){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(con);
    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle(title);
    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage(err);
    // Setting Positive "Yes" Button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("YES", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            // Write your code here to invoke YES event
            Toast.makeText(con, "You clicked on YES", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });

    // Setting Negative "NO" Button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("NO", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Write your code here to invoke NO event
            Toast.makeText(con, "You clicked on NO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();

     }
```

import this `import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;`

Comment: Replace the line `alertDialog.show();` with `alertDialog.create().show();`

Comment: Dear are you calling this in any background thread (`AsyncTask`) ?

Comment: I'm calling this as  switch (dtt){
                        case "10" :ClassName.AlertBox("Message", "Error");

Comment: as you customised this method but you didnt pass the `context` of your activity. Pass `YourActivity.this` as third Argument. and do not use `getApplicationContext()`